# Django template - "Template" object has no attribute "split"

Tags: django, django-templates, jinja2

I am using jinja2 to render a template in django:

Template settings:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        "DIRS": [],
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        "OPTIONS": {
            "context_processors": [
                "django.template.context_processors.debug",
                "django.template.context_processors.request",
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
            ]
        },
    },
    {"BACKEND": "django.template.backends.jinja2.Jinja2", "DIRS": ["utils/"]},
]
```

Calling code:

```
html_template = get_template("email/contact/contact.html") #completes successfully - template definitely found

html_message = render_to_string(html_template, context)
```

This gives the error:

```
AttributeError: 'Template' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Googling this only shows solutions for:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'

Which suggests that the template is not found. This is not the case here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`render_to_string` takes a template name, not an object. You don't need to call `get_template`.

```
html_message = render_to_string("email/contact/contact.html", context)
```